# Having trouble adding a pause function on javascript game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, event-listener

I am trying to figure out how when the page loads the game is "paused" and the user has to hit enter to play and when the user does so the game starts.

Here are the current keystates to control the player when the game is active. I feel like I'm almost there (correct me if I'm wrong), but I just can't get what makes the canvas "pause" when the page is loaded and how to make it "play" when the enter button is pushed.

```
keystate = {};
  document.addEventListener('enter', function(evt){
    keystate[evt.keyCode] = true;
  });
  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(evt){
    keystate[evt.keyCode] = true;
  });
  document.addEventListener('keyup', function(evt){
    delete keystate[evt.keyCode];
  });
```

Comment: How are you dealing with `keystate` object ? Provided code does not make any sense..

Comment: it is better to do `keystate[evt.keyCode]= false` instead of deleting the property

Answer (score 0):

I have two ways,

- One simple, but not so nice
- One hard, can be nice

> The first ay is just alerting something with `comfirm(text)`.

Here is the code for that way :

```js
var gameBrightness = 10; 

function pause() {
    var pause = confirm("You paused the game, click 'OK' to continue your game and the other button to go to options"); 
      
    if (pause == false) { //Didn't click on OK
      var options = confirm("Click on 'Ok' to not change brigthness, but the other one to change the brightness to a random value");
      
      if (options == true) { //Clicked on OK
         ReDopause();
         return;
      }
      else { //Didn't click on OK
         brightness = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
         document.getElementById("brightness").innerHTML = brightness;
         ReDopause();
         return;
      }
    }
 }

 var ReDopause = function() {
    pause(); 
 }
```

```html
<button onclick="pause()">Pause</button>
<span id="brightness">brigthness : 10</span>
```

The second way I havn't made but it is in each movements or timers add an `if` statment. Like this:

```
var pause = false;
setInerval(tick, 100);

function tick() {
  if (pause == false) {
     ....
  }
}
```

At the bginnning you should have a canvas which isn't visible which is the pause menu. Here gow you do the CSS for that:

```
#pause {
  display: none;
  ...
}
```

When you pause set `pause` to `true`, set your main canvas to `document.getElementById("mainCanvas").style.display = "none"` this will make the canvas dissapear but still with all it's drawings. Then show the `pause` canvas like this : `document.getElementById("mainCanvas").style.display = "initial"`. The when "Continue" is clicked: set pause to `false` and to the contrary of this.